# Rails, number_field_tag direct goto record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for a way, how a user can type the ID of a record (i.e. /controller/23) , then press the goto button and it navigates directly to  /controller/id

So the user is on the index page. There is something like a number_field_tag (input field), wrapped inside a form? You type the ID of the record and then click GOTO.

I don't want to explain to a user they can do this simply by changing the URL, so i prefer a solution that uses the page.

Preferable non javascript. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll either need to write another action to handle the translation of submission -> redirection to the URL cleanly or use a javascript solution in my opinion.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('form')  // replace with a more detailed selector of your form (e.g. #formid)
    .submit(function() {
      window.location.href = 'http://foo.bar/controller/' + $('#field-id').val();
      return false;
    });
</script>
```

That bit of JS will accomplish what you need if you decided that a JS approach is satisfactory.

Comment: You'll have to do a bit of work to that, as having http://foo.bar in there fixed isn't very adaptable (it should read the current window.location.href and extract the protocol+domain part, retaining it), but yeah, that's the general jist of the js solution.

Comment: ok, thanks, Was 'afraid' its either a controller action or JS. Well guess, not a nice clean way.

Answer (score -1):

I think this might do

```
<%= link_to "GOTO" XXX_path(params[:id_of_field]), :class=>"STYLE_AS_BUTTON" %>
```

Comment: `params[:id_of_field]` will only be present after the form has been submitted, not on the page where the submission will take place.

Comment: I'm not sure how this works. I need to place this inside a form? The params[] can't get the value of the field just by clicking the link. Exactly James, thats available inside the controller not on the form.